# Error when calling h2o predict

Tags: r, h2o

When using h2o in R, I get an error when trying to call the predict function on a model object:

```
Error in .h2o.calcBaseURL(conn = conn, h2oRestApiVersion =    h2oRestApiVersion,  : 
no slot of name "https" for this object of class "H2OConnection"
```

What's going on?

**Edit**
I noticed since I upgraded to the latest h2o version, I also get this error when trying to load previously created model objects:

```
Error in .model.parts(o) : 
trying to get slot "metrics" from an object of a basic class ("NULL")  with no slots
```

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example. Error messages alone are rarely helpful in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H2O does not currently allow you to access models built in one version of H2O from another version. In other words, you can only access models from the H2O version they were orginally built in.